# I want to add Scroll Limit to Fixed Footer using CSS

Tags: html, css, fixed

How do I add Scroll limit to my **footer**, I mean i dont want my footer to follow me at the top of my page.I want to add limit to it. here is my CSS:

```
        #footer
        {
            position:fixed;      
            display:none;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            /*min-height: 80px;*/
            text-align:center;
            background: transparent;
       }
```

Comment: add the html stuffs also please.

Comment: Do you want the footer to be visible all the time, or only when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page? Why did you set 'display: none'?

Answer (score 0):

You may use javascript (jQuery) to do that. In your css you'll have two classes: `.footer`, and `.sticky_footer`. And then - toggle these two classes via jQuery, for instance.

```
var footer = $('.footer'),
    $window = $(window);
$window.on('scroll', function(){
    if( $window.scrollTop() > 1200 ) {
        footer.addClass('sticky_footer');
    } else {
        footer.removeClass('sticky_footer');
    }
});
```

Of course your conditions and scripting may be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set min-height to page content. for example :

css:
-------------------------------
.content { min-height:400px; }


html:
----------------------
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div class="content">
        content here ...
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        footer content here ...
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```